# Convert Part of an Expression Using ExpToTrig

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I'm wondering if there's a nice way to convert only parts of an expression, say exponential functions of varible $\theta$ to trig. The motivation is best descripbed by the following example.

```
DSolve[{{-(1/2) I \[Theta] b[t] (I Cos[\[Phi]] + Sin[\[Phi]]), -(1/2)
   E^(I \[Phi]) \[Theta] a[t]} == {a'[t], b'[t]}, a[0] == a0, 
   b[0] == b0}, {a[t], b[t]}, {t}]
```

Gives the following simplified output

```
{{a[t] -> 
1/2 E^(-(1/2) I t \[Theta]) (a0 (1 + E^(I t \[Theta])) - 
  I b0 (-1 + E^(I t \[Theta])) Cos[\[Phi]] - 
  b0 (-1 + E^(I t \[Theta])) Sin[\[Phi]]), 
b[t] -> 1/
2 E^(-(1/2)
   I t \[Theta]) (I a0 E^(I \[Phi]) (-1 + E^(I t \[Theta])) + 
  b0 (1 + E^(I t \[Theta])))}}
```

Or in a bit more readable view
$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 a(t)\to \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \theta  t} \left(a_0 \left(1+e^{i \theta  t}\right)-b_0
   \left(-1+e^{i \theta  t}\right) \sin (\phi )-i b_0 \left(-1+e^{i \theta  t}\right) \cos (\phi )\right)
   \\
 b(t)\to \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \theta  t} \left(i a_0 e^{i \phi } \left(-1+e^{i \theta 
   t}\right)+b_0 \left(1+e^{i \theta  t}\right)\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Calling ExpToTrig and Simplify gives,

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 a(t)\to a_0 \cos \left(\frac{\theta  t}{2}\right)+b_0 \sin \left(\frac{\theta  t}{2}\right) (\cos (\phi
   )-i \sin (\phi )) \\
 b(t)\to b_0 \cos \left(\frac{\theta  t}{2}\right)-a_0 \sin \left(\frac{\theta  t}{2}\right) (\cos (\phi
   )+i \sin (\phi )) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now if I simplify all the trig of variable $\theta$ I get the nicest output

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 a(t)\to a_0 \cos \left(\frac{\theta  t}{2}\right)+b_0 e^{-i \phi } \sin \left(\frac{\theta  t}{2}\right)
   \\
 b(t)\to b_0 \cos \left(\frac{\theta  t}{2}\right)-a_0 e^{i \phi } \sin \left(\frac{\theta  t}{2}\right)
   \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Can anyone suggest a way to automate this procedure? I get that in general, it's a very complex task, but Mathematica has never failed to impress me.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! `ExpToTrig[answer]//FullSimplify` gives desired result.

Comment: @Alx Thanks it does work, but do you have a more general solution

Comment: Well, someone calls this "black art"---to force Mathematica produce the answer one wants. If you `FullSimplify` on the first output (just the solution to differential equations), Mathematica gives for `a(t)` the simplified expression as you want, but for `b(t)` it gives more complicated one. It is strange, from `LeafCount` point of view (MMA tries to simplify by minimizing `length` of expression). So I think there is no general approach, one just need to try different combinations of expressions' transformations. That is why not only `FullSimplify` exists in WL.

Comment: @Alx I get it but would be nice to have the option of simplifying using a pattern or something